# Create a drop down from an xml file, with no repeated values. Do I need an array?

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, variables, drop-down-menu

I am still learning javascript and xml and have recently been presented with an issue I'm sure is simple to solve. I'm hoping for some help on this if possible.

I have an xml file that is found here

http://mrblesid.com/blueprint/bookinglist.xml

I'm currently using this code to create a drop down list featuring the values from just one of the attributes "strArtistName"

```
$(document).ready(function(artists){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "bookinglist.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(artists_list) { 
        var select = $('#mySelect');
        $(artists_list).find('vw_ADM_BookingListNull[strArtistName]').each(function(){
            var artists = $(this).attr('strArtistName');
            select.append('<option value="'+artists+'">'+artists+'</option>');
            });
    select.children(":first").text("please make a selection").attr("selected",true);
    }
    });
});
```

This is then called into a dropdown via the following

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect">
  <option>loading</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I would like to avoid repeating the artist names that are found for every entry, am I right to think I would need to use an array for this? If so how do I go about it?

The name selected from the list should populate a variable to use elsewhere in the report.

Any help would be greatly appreciates as I have deadlines looming.

Thanks in advance,
Mikey

Comment: When you say that you "would like to avoid repeating the artist names that are found for every entry" do you mean that you only want each artist to appear once (no duplicates)?

Comment: YEs that's exactly it. Sorry for the confusion. As each artist can have multiple bookings, they currently appear more than once. I only want their name to appear once in the drop down. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array will work. Update the main part to

```
var artistsArr = [];
$(artists_list).find('vw_ADM_BookingListNull[strArtistName]').each(function(){
    var artists = $(this).attr('strArtistName');
    if ($.inArray(artists, artistsArr) == -1) {
        select.append('<option value="'+artists+'">'+artists+'</option>');
        artistsArr.push(artists);
    }
});
```

Some browsers don't support `Array.indexOf`, so you can use jQuery's `inArray`.

Comment: Hi,sorry to be a pain but I'd like to also use the selected value to populate a variable to be used elsewhere in my code. so what I'm after now is how to pass the selected value of #mySelect into a variable. Are you able to help?

Comment: Sure. I think this is what you want `var selectVal = $("#mySelect").val();`. the jQuery docs say this works too `$("#mySelect option:selected").val()`. But the first one should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should batch the DOM insertions for performance reasons (You can also squeeze a little more performance out by using an array instead of pure string concatanation)  Here is your success function with some performance optimizations as well as the check for duplicate artists:

```
function(artists_list) { 
    var select = $('#mySelect'),
        html = [],
        artistArray = [];

    $(artists_list).find('vw_ADM_BookingListNull[strArtistName]').each(function(){
        var artists = $(this).attr('strArtistName');

        // Check the artistArray for a duplicate.
        // This will only work in more recent browsers.
        if (artistArray.indexOf(artists) === -1) {
            html.push('<option value="'+artists+'">'+artists+'</option>');
            artistArray.push(artists);
        }
    });

    // Join the HTML array and add it to the select element
    select.append(html.join(''))
      .children(":first").text("please make a selection").attr("selected",true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Noah, but I'm going to use the above answer to tackle any potential issues with indexOf.